# Need Suggestion.

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How to debug "NameError: global name 'X' is not defined" in Python? I am pretty much new in Python. I am using jupyter_notebook with Python 2.7 to execute code. I am facing following error.

My code:

```
logFile = "NASAlog.txt"

def parseLogs():
    parsed_logs=(sc
            .textFile(logFile)
            .map(parseApacheLogLine)
            .cache())

    access_logs = (parsed_logs
            .filter(lambda s: s[1] == 1)
            .map(lambda s: s[0])
            .cache())

    failed_logs = (parsed_logs
            .filter(lambda s: s[1] == 0)
            .map(lambda s: s[0]))
    failed_logs_count = failed_logs.count()
    if failed_logs_count > 0:
        print 'Number of invalid logline: %d' % failed_logs.count()
        for line in failed_logs.take(20):
            print 'Invalid logline: %s' % line

    print 'Read %d lines, successfully parsed %d lines, failed to parse %d lines' % (parsed_logs.count(), access_logs.count(), failed_logs.count())
    return parsed_logs, access_logs, failed_logs

parsed_logs, access_logs, failed_logs = parseLogs()
```

ERROR

```
> NameError   Traceback (most recent call last) 
>           <ipython-input-18-b365aa793252> in <module>()
>      24     return parsed_logs, access_logs, failed_logs
>      25 
> ---> 26 parsed_logs, access_logs, failed_logs = parseLogs()
> 
> <ipython-input-18-b365aa793252> in parseLogs()
>       2 
>       3 def parseLogs():
> ----> 4     parsed_logs=(sc
>       5             .textFile(logFile)
>       6             .map(parseApacheLogLine)
> 
> NameError: global name 'sc' is not defined
```

Comment: where do you define the variable `sc`?

Comment: Please make your question title informant of the actual problem at hand in the first place, as opposed to a ridiculously broad statement such as "Need urgent suggestion".

Comment: BTW: Nice to have a NASA engineer here. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did never define sc. Therefore python can't find it. (Makes sense, doesn't it?)

Now there are several possible reasons:
- python is case-sensitive. Did you somewhere define SC instead of sc? ... Or Sc instead of sc?

- You defined sc in another function (-> you defined it in a function outside parseLogs()). If you only define it there the variable will be local and just be available to the code inside the function. Add the line `global sc` to the first line of your function to make it accessible everywhere in you whole code.
- You simply did not define sc.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts here - your profile card is enough to establish authorship.